# Convert C# Websocket example to Unity MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

Bit of a C# noob.
Trying to use the Websocket CSharp library
http://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/
to create a socket server in Unity.
How would I convert the following to a **Monobehaviour** so I can simply attach to a gameobject and run?
I know obviously I am extending Monobehaviour and I am dealing with **Awake**, **Start** and **Update** methods, but a bit fuzzy when it comes to nested classes, namespaces , what code in the following I would put in my **Start** method, and whether I should keep everything in just one .cs file or break it up, one file per class.

```
using System;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace Example
{
  public class Laputa : WebSocketBehavior
  {
    protected override void OnMessage (MessageEventArgs e)
    {
      var msg = e.Data == "BALUS"
      ? "I've been balused already..."
      : "I'm not available now.";

      Send (msg);
    }
  }

  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      var wssv = new WebSocketServer ("ws://dragonsnest.far");
      wssv.AddWebSocketService<Laputa> ("/Laputa");
      wssv.Start ();
      Console.ReadKey (true);
      wssv.Stop ();
    }
  }
}


using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;

namespace Example
{
  public class Laputa : WebSocketBehavior
  {
    protected override void OnMessage (MessageEventArgs e)
    {
      var msg = e.Data == "BALUS"
      ? "I've been balused already..."
      : "I'm not available now.";

      Send (msg);
    }
  }

  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      var wssv = new WebSocketServer ("ws://dragonsnest.far");
      wssv.AddWebSocketService<Laputa> ("/Laputa");
      wssv.Start ();
      Console.ReadKey (true);
      wssv.Stop ();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: here is a tutorial on how to use wesockets with Unity/C# https://github.com/pudility/unityWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd declare the wssv variable as a class variable, at the top of your MonoBehavior.

Initialization (constructing wssv, up through calling Start()) goes in Start().

Input checking (which would replace your Console.ReadKey) goes in Update().
You'll want to check for Input.GetKeyDown() if you want to stop when (ex. Escape) key is pressed, then call Stop on the wssv object.

Generally in Unity3d we keep separate classes in separate files, even when they're short. So I'd recommend moving the Laputa class into a file of its own (and it shouldn't be a MonoBehavior). After that you're MonoBehavior file will have the variable declaration, Start() and Update(). Very clean.